# HugePages on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi4, armv8, huge-pages

I need help about managing Hugepages on raspberry pi 4 running raspberry pi OS 64 bit.
I did not find much reliable information online.
First I recompiled the kernel source enabling `Memory Management options --->Transparent Hugepage Support` option.
When I run the command:

`grep -i huge /proc/meminfo`

The output is:

```
AnonHugePages:    319488 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 k
```

and running the command:

```
cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

the output is:

```
[always] madvise never
```

So I think Transparent Huge Pages (AnonHugePages) should be set.
I need to use HugePages to map the largest contiguous memory chunk using mmap function, c code.

```
mem = mmap(NULL,buf_size,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
```

Looking at https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html there are two flags to manage the hugepages: MAP_HUGETLB flag and MAP_HUGE_2MB, MAP_HUGE_1GB  flag.

My question is: To use HugePages should I map in this way?

```
mem = mmap(NULL,buf_size,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,MAP_HUGETLB,fd,0);
```

Kernel configuration:

```
CONFIG_SYS_SUPPORTS_HUGETLBFS=y
CONFIG_ARCH_WANT_HUGE_PMD_SHARE=y
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE=y
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_HUGE_VMAP=y
CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE=y
CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE_ALWAYS=y
# CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE_MADVISE is not set
CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGE_PAGECACHE=y
# CONFIG_HUGETLBFS is not set
```

Comment: What is set for hugepages on the kernel cmdline?

Comment: @stark i am not sure i got your question

Comment: The kernel cmdline is the set of options passed to the kernel at boot.

Comment: @stark How can i check that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Huge pages are a way to enhance the performances of the applications by reducing the number of TLB misses. The mechanism coalesces contiguous standard physical pages (typical size of 4 KB) into a big one (e.g. 2 MB). Linux implements this feature in two flavors: Transparent Huge pages and explicit huge pages.

## Transparent Huge Pages

Transparent huge pages (THP) are managed transparently by the kernel. The user space applications have no control on them. The kernel makes its best to allocate huge pages whenever it is possible but it is not guaranteed. Moreover, THP may introduce overhead as an underlying "garbage collector" kernel daemon named **khugepaged** is in charge of the coalescing of the physical pages to make huge pages. This may consume CPU time with undesirable effects on the performances of the running applications. In systems with time critical applications, it is generally advised to deactivate THP.

THP can be disabled on the boot command line (cf. the end of this answer) or from the shell in *sysfs*:

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always [madvise] never
$ sudo sh -c "echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled"
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
```

**N.B.**: Some interesting papers exist on the performance evaluation/issues of the THP:

- [Transparent Hugepages: measuring the performance impact](https://alexandrnikitin.github.io/blog/transparent-hugepages-measuring-the-performance-impact/);
- [Settling the Myth of Transparent HugePages for Databases](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/03/06/settling-the-myth-of-transparent-hugepages-for-databases/).

## Explicit huge pages

If the huge pages are required at application level (i.e. from user space). **HUGETLBFS** kernel configuration must be set to activate the **hugetlbfs** pseudo-filesystem (the menu in the kernel configurator is something like: "File systems" --> "Pseudo filesystems" --> "HugeTLB file system support"). In the kernel source tree this parameter is in *fs/Kconfig*:

```
config HUGETLBFS
    bool "HugeTLB file system support"
    depends on X86 || IA64 || SPARC64 || (S390 && 64BIT) || \
           SYS_SUPPORTS_HUGETLBFS || BROKEN
    help
      hugetlbfs is a filesystem backing for HugeTLB pages, based on
      ramfs. For architectures that support it, say Y here and read
      <file:Documentation/admin-guide/mm/hugetlbpage.rst> for details.

      If unsure, say N.
```

For example, on an Ubuntu system, we can check:

```sh
$ cat /boot/config-5.4.0-53-generic | grep HUGETLBFS
CONFIG_HUGETLBFS=y
```

**N.B.**: On Raspberry Pi, it is possible to configure the apparition of */proc/config.gz* and do the same with *zcat* to check the parameter. To make it, the configuration menu is: "General setup" --> "Kernel .config support" + "Enable access to .config through /proc/config.gz"

When this parameter is set, **hugetlbfs** pseudo-filesystem is added into the kernel build (cf. *fs/Makefile*):

```
obj-$(CONFIG_HUGETLBFS)     += hugetlbfs/
```

The source code of **hugetlbfs** is located in *fs/hugetlbfs/inode.c*. At startup, the kernel will mount internal **hugetlbfs** file systems to support all the available huge page sizes for the architecture it is running on:

```c
static int __init init_hugetlbfs_fs(void)
{
    struct vfsmount *mnt;
    struct hstate *h;
    int error;
    int i;

    if (!hugepages_supported()) {
        pr_info("disabling because there are no supported hugepage sizes\n");
        return -ENOTSUPP;
    }

    error = -ENOMEM;
    hugetlbfs_inode_cachep = kmem_cache_create("hugetlbfs_inode_cache",
                    sizeof(struct hugetlbfs_inode_info),
                    0, SLAB_ACCOUNT, init_once);
    if (hugetlbfs_inode_cachep == NULL)
        goto out;

    error = register_filesystem(&hugetlbfs_fs_type);
    if (error)
        goto out_free;

    /* default hstate mount is required */
    mnt = mount_one_hugetlbfs(&hstates[default_hstate_idx]);
    if (IS_ERR(mnt)) {
        error = PTR_ERR(mnt);
        goto out_unreg;
    }
    hugetlbfs_vfsmount[default_hstate_idx] = mnt;

    /* other hstates are optional */
    i = 0;
    for_each_hstate(h) {
        if (i == default_hstate_idx) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        mnt = mount_one_hugetlbfs(h);
        if (IS_ERR(mnt))
            hugetlbfs_vfsmount[i] = NULL;
        else
            hugetlbfs_vfsmount[i] = mnt;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;

 out_unreg:
    (void)unregister_filesystem(&hugetlbfs_fs_type);
 out_free:
    kmem_cache_destroy(hugetlbfs_inode_cachep);
 out:
    return error;
}
```

A **hugetlbfs** file system is a sort of RAM file system into which the kernel creates files to back the memory regions mapped by the applications.

The amount of needed huge pages can be reserved by writing the number of needed huge pages into */sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-**hugepagesize**/nr_hugepages*.

Then, *mmap()* is able to map some part of the application address space onto huge pages. Here is an example showing how to do it:

```c
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define HP_SIZE  (2 * 1024 * 1024) // <-- Adjust with size of the supported HP size on your system

int main(void)
{
  char *addr, *addr1;

  // Map a Huge page
  addr = mmap(NULL, HP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED| MAP_HUGETLB, -1, 0);
  if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap()");
    return 1;
  }

  printf("Mapping located at address: %p\n", addr);

  pause();

  return 0;
}
```

In the preceding program, the memory pointed by *addr* is based on huge pages. Example of usage:

```
$ gcc alloc_hp.c -o alloc_hp
$ ./alloc_hp
mmap(): Cannot allocate memory
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
0
$ sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages"
$  cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
1
$ ./alloc_hp 
Mapping located at address: 0x7f7ef6c00000
```

In another terminal, the process map can  be observed to verify the size of the memory page (it is blocked in *pause()* system call):

```
$ pidof alloc_hp
13009
$ cat /proc/13009/smaps
[...]
7f7ef6c00000-7f7ef6e00000 rw-s 00000000 00:0f 331939     /anon_hugepage (deleted)
Size:               2048 kB
KernelPageSize:     2048 kB   <----- The page size is 2MB
MMUPageSize:        2048 kB
[...]
```

In the preceding map, the file name */anon_hugepage* for the huge page region is made internally by the kernel. It is marked deleted because the kernel removes the associated memory file which will make the file disappear as soon as there are no longer references on it (e.g. when the calling process ends, the underlying file is closed upon *exit()*, the reference counter on the file drops to 0 and the remove operation finishes to make it disappear).

## Allocation of other huge page sizes

On Raspberry Pi 4B, the default huge page size is 2MB but the card supports several other huge page sizes:

```
$ ls -l /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Nov 23 14:58 hugepages-1048576kB
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Nov 23 14:58 hugepages-2048kB
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Nov 23 14:58 hugepages-32768kB
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Nov 23 14:58 hugepages-64kB
```

To use them, it is necessary to mount a *hugetlbfs* type file system corresponding to the size of the desired huge page. The [kernel documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/mm/hugetlbpage.rst) provides details on the available mount options. For example, to mount a *hugetlbfs* file system on */mnt/huge* with 8 Huge Pages of size 64KB, the command is:

```
mount -t hugetlbfs -o pagesize=64K,size=512K,min_size=512K none /mnt/huge
```

Then it is possible to map huge pages of 64KB in a user program. The following program creates the */tmp/hpfs* directory on which it mounts a *hugetlbfs* file system with a size of 4 huge pages of 64KB. A file named /memfile_01 is created and extended to the size of 2 huge pages. The file is mapped into memory thanks to *mmap()* system call. It is not passed **MAP_HUGETLB** flag as the provided file descriptor is for a file created on a *hugetlbfs* filesystem. Then, the program calls *pause()* to suspend its execution in order to make some observations in another terminal:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


#define ERR(fmt, ...) do {                            \
    fprintf(stderr,                                   \
            "ERROR@%s#%d: "fmt,                       \
             __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ## __VA_ARGS__); \
                         } while(0)


#define HP_SIZE   (64 * 1024)
#define HPFS_DIR  "/tmp/hpfs"
#define HPFS_SIZE (4 * HP_SIZE)


int main(void)
{
void *addr;
char  cmd[256];
int   status;
int   rc;
char  mount_opts[256];
int   fd;

  rc = mkdir(HPFS_DIR, 0777);
  if (0 != rc && EEXIST != errno) {
    ERR("mkdir(): %m (%d)\n", errno);
    return 1;
  }

  snprintf(mount_opts, sizeof(mount_opts), "pagesize=%d,size=%d,min_size=%d", HP_SIZE, 2*HP_SIZE, HP_SIZE);

  rc = mount("none", HPFS_DIR, "hugetlbfs", 0, mount_opts);
  if (0 != rc) {
    ERR("mount(): %m (%d)\n", errno);
    return 1;
  }

  fd = open(HPFS_DIR"/memfile_01", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0777);
  if (fd < 0) {
    ERR("open(%s): %m (%d)\n", "memfile_01", errno);
    return 1;
  }

  rc = ftruncate(fd, 2 * HP_SIZE);
  if (0 != rc) {
    ERR("ftruncate(): %m (%d)\n", errno);
    return 1;
  }

  addr = mmap(NULL, 2 * HP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
  if (MAP_FAILED == addr) {
    ERR("mmap(): %m (%d)\n", errno);
    return 1;
  }

  // The file can be closed
  rc = close(fd);
  if (0 != rc) {
    ERR("close(%d): %m (%d)\n", fd, errno);
    return 1;
  }

  pause();

  return 0;

} // main
```

The preceding program must be run as root as it calls *mount()*:

```
$ gcc mount_tlbfs.c -o mount_tlbfs
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-64kB/nr_hugepages 
0
$ sudo sh -c "echo 8 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-64kB/nr_hugepages"
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-64kB/nr_hugepages 
8
$ sudo ./mount_tlbfs
```

In another terminal, the */proc/[pid]/smaps* file can be displayed to check the huge page allocation. As soon as the program writes into the huge pages, the Lazy allocation mechanism triggers the effective allocation of the huge pages.

Cf. This [article](http://www.rkoucha.fr/raspberry_pi/rpi4b_hp_alloc.html) for future details

## Early reservation

The huge pages are made with consecutive physical memory pages. The reservation should be done early in the system startup (especially on heavy loaded systems) as the physical memory may be so fragmented that it is sometimes impossible to allocate huge pages afterward. To reserve as early as possible, this can be done on the kernel [boot command line](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt):

```
hugepages=  
       [HW] Number of HugeTLB pages to allocate at boot.
       If this follows hugepagesz (below), it specifies
       the number of pages of hugepagesz to be allocated.
       If this is the first HugeTLB parameter on the command
       line, it specifies the number of pages to allocate for
       the default huge page size.  See also
       Documentation/admin-guide/mm/hugetlbpage.rst.
       Format: <integer>

hugepagesz=
        [HW] The size of the HugeTLB pages.  This is used in
        conjunction with hugepages (above) to allocate huge
        pages of a specific size at boot.  The pair
        hugepagesz=X hugepages=Y can be specified once for
        each supported huge page size. Huge page sizes are
        architecture dependent.  See also
        Documentation/admin-guide/mm/hugetlbpage.rst.
        Format: size[KMG]

transparent_hugepage=
        [KNL]
        Format: [always|madvise|never]
        Can be used to control the default behavior of the system
        with respect to transparent hugepages.
        See Documentation/admin-guide/mm/transhuge.rst
        for more details.
```

On Raspberry Pi, the boot command line can typically be updated in */boot/cmdline.txt* and the current boot command line used by the running kernel can be seen in */proc/cmdline*.

**N.B.**:

- This recipe is explained in more details [here](http://www.rkoucha.fr/raspberry_pi/rpi4b_hp_config.html) and [here](http://www.rkoucha.fr/raspberry_pi/rpi4b_hp_alloc.html)
- There is a user space library called [libhugetlbfs](https://linux.die.net/man/7/libhugetlbfs) which offers a layer of abstraction on top of the kernel's *hugetlbfs* mechanism described here. It comes with library services like [get_huge_pages()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/get_huge_pages) and accompanying tools like [hugectl](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hugectl). The goal of this user space service is to map the heap and text+data segments of **STATICALLY** linked executables into huge pages (the mapping of dynamically linked programs is not supported). All of this relies on the kernel features described in this answer.

Comment: When i run the command  cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages the output is: No such file or directory

Comment: What is the configuration of your kernel ? If you have installed config.gz : zcat /proc/config.gz | grep HUGE. Add the result of this in your question...

Comment: I added the result in the question.

Comment: You need to configure CONFIG_HUGETLBFS I guess

Comment: OK, Do you know how ? because using make menuconfig i did not find others HugePages options. Should i edit the .config file ?

Comment: I don't have any RPI 4 but only RPI 3 (which does not support HP). I guess that hugetlbfs is located in file system config as the parameter is located in "fs/Kconfig" in the kernel source tree.

Comment: Looking at .config file in the linux directory there is  the entry # CONFIG_HUGETLBFS is not set, but i do not know how i can edit and enable it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224801/discussion-between-rachid-k-and-nick).